# jQuery check URL and then show and hide elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have multiple sliders on my page, I am using a plugin called [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/). On page load I have all my class `newsarticle` hidden but show the first parent as you may be able to see below in my code, my sliders are split into years; year2003, year2004 etc.

I have everything on a single page, therefore a URL such as wwww.example1.com/year2004.html wouldn't work take me to year2004 slider, but I know I can use the following method:

`www.example1.com/index.html#2003_concorde`

This jumps to that ID on the page, which is great as it directs me to a specific story, however as I have my other sliders hidden by default if I try to jump to the following URL:

`www.example1.com/index.html#2004_firefox` or `www.example1.com/index.html#year_2004`

This will not show the corresponding div, as well because it is hidden by default by jQuery and is only unhidden when I use my HTML Range Slider.

#### What I have tried so far

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
     if(window.location.href.indexOf("#digitl2004")) {
       // hide elements
                $('.newsarticle').hide();
                  $('.most_popular_contents').hide();                

                //show elements
                $('#digitl2004').fadeIn('fast');
                  $('.news_content_2004').fadeIn('fast');               


                // bg image change
                var image = $('#maincontent');
                image.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                image.css('background-image','url(images/facebook.jpg)');
                image.fadeIn('fast');
                });    }
      });
 </script>
```

What I'm trying to do above is to check the URL that has been inputted and if the URL has the existence of #digitl2004 then i want it to hide the elements as above.

However this has worked to no avail! I'm no expert on JS but I envision it can work the way I have tried above, or if I can get the JS to change the slider value depending on URL inserted i.e. if digitl2004 is in the URL then the range slider value will change to 2004.

index.html

```
<div id="digitl2003" class="newsarticle year2003"> <!-- Start Year 2003 -->
    <div class="newsyear">
        <h2 class="timeline_year">2003</h2>
    </div> <!-- End Div News Year -->
        <ul class="bxslider">
            <li>
                <div class="newselement" id="2003_safari">
                <h3 class="timeline_heading">Safari Browser launched</h3>

                        <p class="timeline_content">On January 7th 2003, at Macworld in San Francisco, Steve Jobs announces that Apple are releasing their own web browser, Safari. Subsequent releases of the browser follow with the full version 1.0 release on June 23 2003.</p>
                        <p class="timeline_content">Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_browser#Safari_1" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a></p>
                            <div class="newsshareicons">
                               <div class="wrapper">

                                <img src="images/facebook_icon.png" id="2003_safari_share_fb" alt="Share on Facebook" title="Share on Facebook"/>
                                <a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=In%202003%20Steve%20Jobs%20announces%20that%20Apple%20are%20releasing%20their%20own%20browser%20Safari%20#DIGI.T.L." target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter_icon.png" id="2003_safari_share_twitter" alt="Share on Twitter" title="Share on Twitter"/></a>
                                <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/linkedin_icon.png" id="2003_safari_share_linkedin" alt="Share on LinkedIn" title="Share on Linekdin"/></a>
                                <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/googleplus_icon.png" id="2003_safari_share_googleplus" alt="Share on Google+" title="Share on Google+"/></a>
                               </div> <!-- End Wrapper -->
                           </div> <!-- End News Share Icon --> 

                </div> <!-- End News Element -->
            </li>  <!-- End List -->

            <li>
                <div class="newselement" id="2003_concorde">
                <h3 class="timeline_heading">The end of Concorde</h3>
                        <p class="timeline_content">Concorde ends three decades of supersonic travel when, on 26th November 2003 the last Concorde lands at its new home at Filton Airfield; the airfield where it was built.</p>
                        <p class="timeline_content">Source: <a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/england/bristol/3238674.stm" target="_blank">BBC News</a></p>
                </div>
                  <div class="newsshareicons">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <img src="images/facebook_icon.png" id="2003_concorde_share_fb" alt="Share on Facebook" title="Share on Facebook"/>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=Concorde%20ends%20three%20decades%20of%20supersonic%20travel%20on%2026th%20November%202003%20#DIGI.T.L." target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter_icon.png" id="2003_concorde_share_twitter" alt="Share on Twitter" title="Share on Twitter"/></a>
                            <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
                            <img src="images/linkedin_icon.png" id="2003_concorde_share_linkeidn" alt="Share on LinkedIn" title="Share on Linekdin"/>
                            <img src="images/googleplus_icon.png" id="2003_concorde_share_googleplus" alt="Share on Google+" title="Share on Google+"/>
                       </div> <!-- End Wrapper -->
                </div> <!-- End News Share Icon --> 
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="newselement" id="2003_genome">
                <h3 class="timeline_heading">Human Genome Project completed</h3>

                        <p class="timeline_content">In April 2003 it is announced that the project to sequence the human genome is complete. The mapping is now close to 100% complete, with only very small gaps left which are considered too costly to fill in at this point.</p>
                        <p class="timeline_content">Source: <a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/sci/tech/2940601.stm" target="_blank">BBC News</a></p>
                </div>
                 <div class="newsshareicons">
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                <img src="images/facebook_icon.png" id="2003_genome_share_fb" alt="Share on Facebook" title="Share on Facebook"/>
                                <img src="images/twitter_icon.png" id="2003_genome_share_twitter" alt="Share on Twitter" title="Share on Twitter"/>
                                <img src="images/linkedin_icon.png" id="2003_genome_share_linkeidn" alt="Share on LinkedIn" title="Share on Linekdin"/>
                                <img src="images/googleplus_icon.png" id="2003_genome_share_googleplus" alt="Share on Google+" title="Share on Google+"/>
                               </div> <!-- End Wrapper -->
                </div> <!-- End News Share Icon --> 
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div><!-- End Year2003 -->
```

Js/js.js

```
 $('.newsarticle').hide();
 $('.newsarticle:first-child').show();
```

### UPDATE

When I use a click event as below:

It works, however without the click event this will not work? Not sure why

```
  <a href="#" id="link">change</a>

<script>
    $(function() {
        window.onhashchange = function () {

        }



        $('#link').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.hash = 'digitl2004';

            // hide elements
                        $('.newsarticle').hide();  
                        $('.most_popular_contents').hide();                
                    //show elements
                        $('#digitl2004').fadeIn('fast');
                        $('.news_content_2004').fadeIn('fast');           

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you can make a jsfiddle demo

Comment: seem like not all browsers refresh the page on a hash link click, so the code doesn't get rerun when the hash is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(window.location.href.indexOf("#digitl2004"))`

should be

`if(window.location.hash==='#digitl2004')`

since it's the hash you seem to be concerned with.

**updated code**

html

```
<a href="#digitl2004" class="pink">test link</a>
<div id="digitl2003" class="newsarticle year2003"> <!-- Start Year 2003 -->
    ...
</div>
<div id="digitl2004" class="newsarticle year2004"> <!-- Start Year 2004 -->
    ...
</div>
```

jquery

```
function hash(th) {
    var wh = window.location.hash;
    if (!wh) { wh = th; }//set to href if !hash
    if(wh==='#digitl2004') {//if hash ===
        $('#maincontent').fadeOut('fast')//fade out image
        .css('background-image','url(images/facebook.jpg)')//change background
        .fadeIn('fast');//fade in image
    }
    if (wh) {//if wh exists
        $(wh).fadeIn('fast')//fade in selected
        .siblings('.newsarticle').fadeOut('fast');//fadeout siblings
    }
}
hash();//inital run
$('.pink').on('click', function() {
    var th = $(this).attr('href');//get href
    hash(th);//send href
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/HyN76/

click the test link to try it with the `#digitl2004` hash.

Comment: it should. what does it say in your console if you do `console.log(window.location.hash);`?

Comment: it returns #digitl2004 but it isn't showing and hiding my elements at all

Comment: then it's working, just as it does here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/filever10/HyN76/show/light/#digitl2004 . There must be something else going on. what errors do you get, or can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I've updated the example and answer to work with or without the hash in the url.